# mysql select last 7 day query and if are more query in a day sum that and show only the sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to show using `select` mysql the `data_order` is timestamp

1. firstly only the last 7 rows(which to contain the column `price`) from only each day of the last week including today like day-by-day. Suppose I have in every day (last 7 days) a single order is simple, but I don't know how to make the mysql statement when I have more orders in the same day

   ```
   +-------------------------------------------------------------+
   | table name  `comanda`                                       |
   +-------------------------------------------------------------+
   | id_comanda | keyUnique_comanda | pret_comanda| data_comanda |
   +------------+-------------------+-------------+--------------+
   | 1          | a1234             | 150         | today        |
   +------------+-------------------+-------------+--------------+
   | 2          | b4321             | 300         | yesturday    |
   +------------+-------------------+-------------+--------------+
   | 3          | b4321             | 200         | yesturday    |
   +------------+-------------------+-------------+--------------+
   | 4          | c4321             | 100         | yesturday    |
   +------------+-------------------+-------------+--------------+
   | 5          | d234              | 50          | 3 day ago    |
   +------------+-------------------+-------------+--------------+
   | 6          | e453              | 200         | 9 day ago    |
   +------------+-------------------+-------------+--------------+
   ```

I tried something... but is not show me well

```
SELECT DAY(data_comanda) AS period, SUM(pret_comanda) AS total 
FROM comanda 
WHERE data_comanda >= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1  WEEK 
GROUP BY period



-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `comanda`
--

CREATE TABLE `comanda` (
  `id_comanda` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pret_comanda` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pret_comanda_total` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comanda` text NOT NULL,
  `nume_comanda` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `prenume_comanda` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email_comanda` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `telefon_comanda` varchar(19) NOT NULL,
  `judet_comanda` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `adresa_comanda` varchar(2555) NOT NULL,
  `clientIP` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `localitate_comanda` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `detalii_comanda` varchar(3000) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `data_comanda` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `data_comanda_finalizare` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `produse_diferite_comanda` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `keyUnique_comanda` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `status_comanda` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'asteptare',
  `admin_validare_comanda` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'neModificat'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Try `- INTERVAL 1  WEEK` instead of `+ INTERVAL 1  WEEK`

Comment: ok but I want to show 7 queries for every day of the week... how I can do that?

Comment: What do you mean? You want 7 rows each day for the last 7 days? Overall 49 rows?

Comment: BTW: How does your query relate to the sample data?

Comment: no, I gave only a e.g. up, I want to show only the column `price` in ONLY 7 ROWS to corresponding with the LAST 7 DAYS, but the problem is HOW to do if for e.g. yesturday I HAD MORE then 1 ORDER (so I have more queries and I WWANT to SHOW only 1 ROWS with SUM  of column `price`)  OTHER PROBLEM is to SHOW 0 if e.g. 3 day ago I DIDNOT HAVE ANY ORDER     e.g. TO SHOW the VALUE PRICE like this DESC (`300, 200, 500, 0, 543, 600, 200`)

Comment: Post sample data and expected result please.

Comment: this is giving me only a ROW with all the sum of the `price` value of the orders which I had in the last 7 days... `SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(data_order) AS period, SUM(price) AS total FROM comanda WHERE data_order >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 WEEK GROUP BY period` AND I WANT to SHOW 7 ROWS for each day with the corresponding SUM(`PRICE`) if are more then 1 order in that DAY

Comment: What is the data type of `data_order`? Post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table_name`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137078/discussion-between-alcatraz007-and-paul-spiegel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
WHERE data_comanda >= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1  WEEK
```

you should use

```
WHERE data_comanda >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1  WEEK
```

But this will include today and the last 7 days (overall 8 days). If you only want 7 days overall you should use

```
WHERE data_comanda >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY
```

The query would now return

```
+--------+-------+
| period | total |
+--------+-------+
|      1 |   600 |
|      2 |   150 |
|     27 |    50 |
+--------+-------+
```

http://rextester.com/QSDUY96504

This might be confusing because `DAY(data_comanda)` returns the day of the month. So you might want to use `DATE` instead of `DAY` and get the result like:

```
+------------+-------+
|   period   | total |
+------------+-------+
| 27.02.2017 |    50 |
| 01.03.2017 |   600 |
| 02.03.2017 |   150 |
+------------+-------+
```

http://rextester.com/XOECI72414

To include the missing days you can create an inline table with numbers from 0 to 6

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 0 as diff UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6
) diffs
```

And now `LEFT JOIN` your table

```
SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL diffs.diff DAY AS period,
       COALESCE(SUM(pret_comanda), 0) AS total
FROM (
    SELECT 0 as diff UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6
) diffs
LEFT JOIN comanda c ON DATE(c.data_comanda) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL diffs.diff DAY
GROUP BY period;
```

Note that `SUM(pret_comanda)` will return NULL for missing days. To convert it to `0` you can use `COALESCE(SUM(pret_comanda), 0)`

Now the result would look like

```
+------------+-------+
|   period   | total |
+------------+-------+
| 24.02.2017 |     0 |
| 25.02.2017 |     0 |
| 26.02.2017 |     0 |
| 27.02.2017 |    50 |
| 28.02.2017 |     0 |
| 01.03.2017 |   600 |
| 02.03.2017 |   150 |
+------------+-------+
```

http://rextester.com/WJD33053

Comment: Thank you, It's work, have a nice day, now I know how to manage this kind of mysql statetament

Comment: Just to show the lack of features in MySQL - here's a PostgreSQL solution: http://rextester.com/ENNV23804